# NSG rule across subscription in azure via terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, alias, terraform-provider-azure, azure-nsg

```
#provider azurem.mgmt is Subscription A.
#prodiver azurem.corpapps is Subscription B.
```

I am trying to create nsg rule in `Subscription A` with Provider `azurerm.mgmt`. Here the `destination application security group` is in `Subscription B` with Provider `azurerm.corpapps`  in this subscription.

```
provider "azurerm" {
    client_id       = "${var.client_id}"
    client_secret   = "${var.client_secret}"
    tenant_id       = "${var.tenant_id}"
    subscription_id = "${var.subscription}"
    alias           = "mgmt"
}

provider "azurerm" {
    client_id       = "${var.client_id}"
    client_secret   = "${var.client_secret}"
    tenant_id       = "${var.tenant_id}"
    subscription_id = "${var.subscription_B}"
    alias           = "corpapps"
}
```

Then i use the provider to get my asg from Subscription B as shown:
[image]

Then i use that reference in my nsg rule
[image]

However, i get error - saying the ASG is not found:
[image]

But, in azure portal the resource is already there as shown:
[image]

Comment: Did you checked your subscription ID, from an error message, are you trying to get info from the correct one? Account from which you are login into Azure, have rights on both subscription?

Comment: According to the Azure Feedback forums there is a limitation which restricts NSGs ability to leverage or assocaite ASGs that are not with int the same location of the target VNET. Are you in different locations? https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/35026777-allow-network-security-groups-nsgs-to-reference

Comment: After my validation, you can not add the ASG from another subscription even it's in the same region as the NSG or target VNet.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out. you can share this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to assign the SP which has owner role on both subscriptions or using Azure account with CLI but it's no luck. Also, as the comment points out, there is a [limitation](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/35026777-allow-network-security-groups-nsgs-to-reference) that NSG does not reference ASG in different location. After my validation, you can not add the ASG from another subscription even it's in the same region as the NSG or targets VNet.

Moreover, when you add this ASG as the target source or destination in the NSG rules, you will see

> Select an application security group (ASG) as the security rule
> source. ASGs enable fine-grained network security policies based on
> workloads or applications instead of IP addresses or CIDR blocks.
> **Rules specifying an application security group are only applied to
> network interfaces that are members of the application security group
> on the same virtual network.**

[image]